# MLFlow Azure Blob Storage Artifact upload times out

Tags: mlflow

I am trying to upload mlflow artifacts to an azure blob storage instance.
The backend server is able to connect to the blob storage and is working fine.
The client is also working fine.
The only issue on the client-side is a time-out while uploading artifacts to the blob storage.
The following exception is thrown:

```
/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/azure/core/pipeline/transport/_requests_basic.py", line 361, in send
raise error
azure.core.exceptions.ServiceResponseError: ('Connection aborted.', timeout('The write operation timed out'))
```

Usually, I would just increase the timeout, but I don't know how to do that for mlflow. I searched for a possible solution [here](https://www.mlflow.org/docs/latest/tracking.html#mlflow-tracking-servers) as well as checking their GitHub for possible open and/or closed issues regarding the same problem, but I have yet to find a solution. Is it possible to adjust the timeout for the artifact logging in mlflow?